# Unable to click on element from dropdown menu item

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, bdd, watir-webdriver

I want to perform following steps:

1. Type some element (variable name - 'username')  in the input area
2. Dropdown suggestions open up. [declaration : username = "user2"]
3. Check if element 'username' is present in dropdown; if yes, then want to click on that element and done.

   ```
   <span class="main-dropdown">
     <div class="tt">
       <span class="all-suggestions">
         <div class="suggestion">
           <p>user1</p>
         </div>
         <div class="suggestion">
           <p>user2</p>
         </div>
         <div class="suggestion">
           <p>user3</p>
         </div>
       </span>
     </div>
   </span>
   ```

I have tried following :

- @browser.div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).wait_while_present
  @browser.div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).click
- @browser.span(:class,"all-suggestions").div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).wait_while_present
  @browser.span(:class,"all-suggestions").div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).click
- @browser.span(:class,"main-dropdown").div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).wait_while_present
  @browser.span(:class,"main-dropdown").div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).click

**Issue:** 'user2' shows up in dropdown list but it is unable to click on that element from dropdown.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the path to the element is over-specified. Watir handles each element method individually, returning the first match of each call. It does not account for chained methods.

For example, consider the first code that does not work:

```
@browser.div(:class,"suggestion").p(:text,username).click
```

Actually says:

1. Find the first div on the page with class "suggestion".
2. Within that div, find the first p with text `username`.

This means that Watir will only find the "user1" paragraph.

When nesting element calls, you only want to include elements that are the same ancestor for all elements. For example, any of the following would work:

```
# Using the only matching div.suggestion
@browser.div(:class => 'suggestion', :text => username).p.click

# Only using the common ancestor span.all-suggestions
@browser.span(:class,"all-suggestions").p(:text,username).click
```

If you really want to keep all of the nesting, you will need to use XPath:

```
@browser.p(:xpath => "//div[@class='suggestion']/p[text()='#{username}']").click
```

Comment: Thanks Justin!. I was able to get this working by - # Using the only matching div.suggestion
@browser.div(:class => 'suggestion', :text => username).p.click but "Only using the common ancestor span.all-suggestions" doesn't work.

Comment: `@browser.span(:class,"all-suggestions").p(:text,username).click` will only work if there is one `span(:class,"all-suggestions")` on the page. This is because Watir returns the first match only.

Comment: got it. Thanks Justin.

Comment: hey @justin..how would you implement the same example above in page object model? I tried something like this: one div locator is: div(:autoSuggestList, :xpath => "//div[contains(@class,'tt-suggestion')]") and then autoSuggestList_element.paragraph_element(:text => /user1/) if I want to check for text 'user1' but this would always check for the first element in the autoSuggestList element. How can we look for all <p> tags within the class=tt-suggestion and then check for existence of some specific text from there?

Comment: Couldn't you just do the same thing as before, but use the respective page-object methods - `div_element(:class => 'suggestion', :text => username).paragraph_element.click`? Or has the HTML also changed - since you seem to now be using a class of "tt-suggestion" instead of just "suggestion".

Comment: Then does it mean that you use the locator element directly in your method and don't define that locator on the top as we do for all other in pages for a page-object pattern?

Comment: Correct. As you need to specify a value, `username`, at runtime, you cannot use the `accessor` methods (as they generated methods do not accept arguments).